# MVC 4 list not binding issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm having a problem with lists and binding. If I have a list with a string name similar to another one. The first one doesn't bound;

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class HomeModel
{
    public List<string> Test { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

And on the View

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Test[0])
    <br/>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Tests[0])
    <br />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

The first test will never get any data bound to it on postback. You have to change the name to Tezt or something. Has anyone seen this?